# How to Self Insert Tab When Editing String In go-mode?

Tags: indentation, tabs, self-insert-command

The title contains the crux of my question. In `go-mode`, tabs and auto-indentation generally works well, except when I am editing strings.

When inside of a string, I'd like the tab key to self-insert. Right now, it does nothing.

Comment: `C-q TAB`. In general, whenever you need to input something that causes self-insert-command to do something other than just appending whatever you typed to the buffer, you could avoid that behavior by prefixing your input with `C-q`.

Comment: @wvxvw Yeah, I am familiar with that. It's just tedious. It seems like there should be a way to automatically turn self-insertion back on, being as that the syntax highlighter recognizes that I am in a string.

Comment: Mmmm... not really. What if you actually wanted to indent your code? I typically don't pay attention to where the point is, when I'm indenting the code. Maybe, specifically in Go one could reason that since saving the file will re-indent it anyway, this isn't very important, yet I do it regardless, especially when file is in the middle of adding changes to it.

Comment: Try `(setq-local tab-always-indent nil)` in `go-mode-hook`. This is not quite what you asked for (does not check if you are in a string), but it would make it easier to insert tabs. (It should be pretty easy to check if you are in a string using `syntax-ppss`, but I don't have the time to test it right now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function below checks if the point is in a string using [`syntax-ppss`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Position-Parse.html#index-syntax_002dppss) and inserts a `TAB` if it is, otherwise calls `indent-for-tab-command`, which is what `TAB` is bound to in `go-mode`.

```el
(defun my-indent-or-insert-tab (arg)
  "Insert TAB if point is in a string, otherwise call
`indent-for-tab-command'."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (nth 3 (syntax-ppss (point)))
      (insert "\t")
    (indent-for-tab-command arg)))
```

Here's one way to get the behavior you need with the help of this function:

```el
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "TAB") #'my-indent-or-insert-tab)))
```

Let me know if this works for you.